# How to break a string into columns, where the character delimiter and comma, but this character appears as content of the fields

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am doing a data load, where each line has the characters "at the beginning and end of the fields, and comma as delimiter, as below:

```
"sU92", "eRouter1.0"
"sU92" "," eRouter1.0 "
"sU9.2", "eRouter1.0"
```

Note that in the second line there are 2 double quotes (2 ") and that in the third row there is a comma between numbers 9 and 2 (9,2).

Whenever I try to create the table with the delimiter being comma and with `quotechar = '\ "'`, the records break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table without un-quoting enabled, use `LasySimpleSerDe`(default)

```
create table mytable(
col1 string,
col2 string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;
```

Then un-quote strings and remove extra spaces in the select using for example `regexp_replace`:

`trim(regexp_replace(str, '\\"',''))`